# Elegant way to ensure a std::map has a concrete size in compilation time

Tags: c++, enums, stdmap, static-assert

I was trying to ensure that a `std::map` has the same size as an `enum` class at compile time. Avoiding the use of macros, if possible.

I tried with `static_assert`, but reading Stack Overflow I concluded that it can't be done because `std::map` is "constructed" at runtime. Or at least it's what I understood. So I get this "expression must be a constant value" error.

Looking at the code must be clearer than my poor explanations:

```
// event_types.h

enum class EventTypes {
  InitSuccessfull,
  KeyPressed,
  StartedCleanup,
  FinishedCleanup,
  Exit,
  count
};

static const std::map<EventTypes, std::string> kEventTypesNames = {
  { EventTypes::InitSuccessfull,  "InitSuccessfull" },
  { EventTypes::KeyPressed,       "KeyPressed" },
  { EventTypes::StartedCleanup,   "StartedCleanup" },
  { EventTypes::FinishedCleanup,  "FinishedCleanup" },
  { EventTypes::Exit,             "Exit" }
};

// this doesn't work, "expression must have a constant value"(kEventTypesNames.size())
static_assert(kEventTypesNames.size() == static_cast<std::underlying_type<kuge::EventTypes>::type>(EventTypes::count));

// this neither works
const unsigned int map_size = kEventTypesNames.size();
static_assert(map_size == static_cast<std::underlying_type<kuge::EventTypes>::type>(EventTypes::count));
```

So, what I want is to ensure that the size of the map is the same as the `enum` count so I don't forget to add the event on both places.

Any idea on how to do it? Or maybe I should think of another (better) way of getting the events "stringified" that doesn't require a map?

Comment: Sorry, no, C++ does not work this way. The most you can do is ensure, at compile time, that the size of an array matches the enum count, and have code that initializes the map from the array.

Comment: Maybe it's time to write a small code generator that produces both the enums and the map initializations?  Shouldn't take more than 15 minutes to create one, and thus be able to handle any amount of EventTypes and map initializers.

Comment: if the map never changes, I'd consider to use a static (sorted) array of `std::pair<EventType,std::string>` instead. It gets you almost all you get from a map minus dynamically inserting/removing elements, which maybe you don't need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the data in a datatype that can be inspected at compile time, such as an array.

```
static const std::map<EventTypes, std::string>::value_type kEventTypesNamesData[] = {
//                      Note "value_type", here ^^^^^^^^^^
  { EventTypes::InitSuccessfull,  "InitSuccessfull" },
  { EventTypes::KeyPressed,       "KeyPressed" },
  { EventTypes::StartedCleanup,   "StartedCleanup" },
  { EventTypes::FinishedCleanup,  "FinishedCleanup" },
  { EventTypes::Exit,             "Exit" }
};

// Compile-time size check
static_assert(end(kEventTypesNamesData)-begin(kEventTypesNamesData) == static_cast<std::underlying_type<EventTypes>::type>(EventTypes::count));

// Construct from data
static const std::map<EventTypes, std::string> kEventTypesNames( begin(kEventTypesNamesData), end(kEventTypesNamesData) );
```

Answer (score 2):

With helper generator, you might do:

```
std::map<EventTypes, std::string> MakeMap()
{ 
    constexpr std::pair<EventTypes, const char*> ini[]
    {
      { EventTypes::InitSuccessfull,  "InitSuccessfull" },
      { EventTypes::KeyPressed,       "KeyPressed" },
      { EventTypes::StartedCleanup,   "StartedCleanup" },
      { EventTypes::FinishedCleanup,  "FinishedCleanup" },
      { EventTypes::Exit,             "Exit" }
    };
    static_assert(std::size_t(EventTypes::count) == std::size(ini));
    return {std::begin(ini), std::end(ini)};
}
static const std::map<EventTypes, std::string> kEventTypesNames = MakeMap();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62501b2db92b3821)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go the "non-code" route, you can create a small code generator that will generate the code.  Then it's just a matter of including that generated code in your program (maybe by using an `#include "generated_code.hpp"` or something similar).

Here is a small one:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// This would be in your data file of enums   
std::string test = "InitSuccessful\n"
                    "KeyPressed\n"
                    "StartedCleanup\n"
                    "FinishedCleanup\n"
                    "AnotherNewEnum1\n"
                    "AnotherNewEnum2\n"
                    "AnotherNewEnum3\n"
                    "Exit";

int main() {
    std::istringstream strmIn(test);
    std::ostringstream enumOut;
    std::ostringstream mapOut;
    std::string line;
    enumOut << "enum class EventTypes {\n";
    mapOut << "static const std::map<EventTypes, std::string> EventTypesNames = {\n";

    while (std::getline(strmIn, line))
    {
        enumOut << "    " << line << ",\n";
        std::string mapStr = "    { EventTypes::" + line + ",  \"" + line + "\" },";
        mapOut << mapStr << "\n";
    }
    enumOut << "    count\n};";
    mapOut << "};";

    // Output the generated source code
    std::cout << enumOut.str() << "\n\n\n";
    std::cout << mapOut.str() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
enum class EventTypes {
    InitSuccessful,
    KeyPressed,
    StartedCleanup,
    FinishedCleanup,
    AnotherNewEnum1,
    AnotherNewEnum2,
    AnotherNewEnum3,
    Exit,
    count
};


static const std::map<EventTypes, std::string> EventTypesNames = {
    { EventTypes::InitSuccessful,  "InitSuccessful" },
    { EventTypes::KeyPressed,  "KeyPressed" },
    { EventTypes::StartedCleanup,  "StartedCleanup" },
    { EventTypes::FinishedCleanup,  "FinishedCleanup" },
    { EventTypes::AnotherNewEnum1,  "AnotherNewEnum1" },
    { EventTypes::AnotherNewEnum2,  "AnotherNewEnum2" },
    { EventTypes::AnotherNewEnum3,  "AnotherNewEnum3" },
    { EventTypes::Exit,  "Exit" },
};
```